# transfer data from an earlier part of a dataframe to a later part based on criteria match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Ok, I tried to figure this one out but I couldn't do it and I couldn't find any other questions quite like it...

Using pandas and a dataframe, I need to match data from an earlier part of a dataframe and put it in a later part of the dataframe, based on a matching value.
The data looks like this:

```
    nc  Date        oldval      lor
508 508 2019-07-08  296.820007  500
509 509 2019-07-17  297.73999   502
510 510 2019-07-19  297.170013  502
511 511 2019-07-25  300         504
512 512 2019-08-05  283.820007  505
513 513 2019-08-12  288.070007  506
514 514 2019-08-14  283.899994  506
515 515 2019-08-23  284.850006  507
516 516 2019-09-03  290.73999   508
517 517 2019-09-16  300.160004  510
518 518 2019-09-24  295.869995  511
519 519 2019-09-27  295.399994  511
520 520 2019-10-02  288.059998  512
521 521 2019-10-08  288.529999  513
522 522 2019-10-18  297.970001  514
523 523 2019-11-21  310.269989  518
524 524 2019-12-03  309.549988  520
```

What I need to do is look at the column 'lor', compare it to all previous rows on the column 'nc', and if 'nc' has a matching value, then put the date into a new column 'xDate' and the 'oldval' into a new column 'xval' on the same line as 'lor'. The numbers in column 'nc' will be unique and increasing in value, while the numbers in the column 'lor' may or may not duplicate.

The final data should look like this:

```
    nc  Date        oldval      lor xdate       xval
508 508 2019-07-08  296.820007  500 np.nan      np.nan
509 509 2019-07-17  297.73999   502 np.nan      np.nan
510 510 2019-07-19  297.170013  502 np.nan      np.nan
511 511 2019-07-25  300         504 np.nan      np.nan
512 512 2019-08-05  283.820007  505 np.nan      np.nan
513 513 2019-08-12  288.070007  506 np.nan      np.nan
514 514 2019-08-14  283.899994  506 np.nan      np.nan
515 515 2019-08-23  284.850006  507 np.nan      np.nan
516 516 2019-09-03  290.73999   508 2019-07-08  296.820007
517 517 2019-09-16  300.160004  510 2019-07-19  297.170013
518 518 2019-09-24  295.869995  511 2019-07-25  300
519 519 2019-09-27  295.399994  511 2019-07-25  300
520 520 2019-10-02  288.059998  512 2019-08-05  283.820007
521 521 2019-10-08  288.529999  513 2019-08-12  288.070007
522 522 2019-10-18  297.970001  514 2019-08-14  283.899994
523 523 2019-11-21  310.269989  518 2019-09-24  295.869995
524 524 2019-12-03  309.549988  520 2019-10-02  288.059998
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` to find the matching values, then convert them to columns with `apply(pd.Series)`.

```
s = df['lor'].apply(lambda x: df.loc[df['nc'] == x, ['Date', 'oldval']].values).explode()  

df[['xdate','xval']] = s.apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas' [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) could help with meeting ur usecase:

```
#reset index
#initialize index to 0, 1, ...
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#merge dataframe on itself
res = (df[['lor','Date','oldval']]
       .merge(df, left_on='lor',right_on='nc',how='left')
       .filter(['Date_y','oldval_y'])
       .set_axis(['xdate','xval'],axis=1)
      )

#concatenate df, res on columns
pd.concat([df,res],axis=1)

    nc  Date         oldval     lor xdate    xval
0   508 2019-07-08  296.820007  500 NaN       NaN
1   509 2019-07-17  297.739990  502 NaN       NaN
2   510 2019-07-19  297.170013  502 NaN       NaN
3   511 2019-07-25  300.000000  504 NaN       NaN
4   512 2019-08-05  283.820007  505 NaN       NaN
5   513 2019-08-12  288.070007  506 NaN       NaN
6   514 2019-08-14  283.899994  506 NaN       NaN
7   515 2019-08-23  284.850006  507 NaN       NaN
8   516 2019-09-03  290.739990  508 2019-07-08  296.820007
9   517 2019-09-16  300.160004  510 2019-07-19  297.170013
10  518 2019-09-24  295.869995  511 2019-07-25  300.000000
11  519 2019-09-27  295.399994  511 2019-07-25  300.000000
12  520 2019-10-02  288.059998  512 2019-08-05  283.820007
13  521 2019-10-08  288.529999  513 2019-08-12  288.070007
14  522 2019-10-18  297.970001  514 2019-08-14  283.899994
15  523 2019-11-21  310.269989  518 2019-09-24  295.869995
16  524 2019-12-03  309.549988  520 2019-10-02  288.059998
```